# How to run collection with data file one row per request, next row per second request and not all rows per each request in postman

Tags: csv, collections, postman, data-files, runner

In postman collection I have 4 requests and I have csv file with data for each of these requests. I'd like to 1st request uses 1st data row, 2nd request uses 2nd data row and so on.

Is there a way to run one row per test?

What I want is to test 1 endpoint with different amount of parameters (all, required, required+some optionals) and different data sets from csv file.

What I got so far with csv is run all requests on 1st row if I select "1 iteration" and if I select "4 iterations" it will run every data row for each request.

My current solution is to use pre-req. and define local variables for each request. But if I need to change them, it's a lot of work for each request, I still want to have a nice csv with all data in one place.